# Display another EditText when certain text is inputed

Tags: android, android-edittext

how to display new `EditText` field below one current `EditText` when 1 character is inputed on first `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

You can set that `EditText` below your current `EditText` and intially set it visibility to `GONE`:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

When you want to show this new `EdiText`, set

```
Edittext textNew=(TextView)mainView.findViewById(R.id.textNew);

textOld.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (s.length()>=1) {
            textNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a TextWatcher
a TextWatcher will watch your EditText for any user interaction use the onTextChanged method to detect user started typing here is how to do it

```
myedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //here add your code
                editetext2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```